# How to add Threads to ParallelAccelerator.jl in julia?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, julia, shared-memory

I was reading the documentations.But I never fond "**By which command I can add threads for ParallelAccelerator.jl**?"
is that `export JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4`
or `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4`?
And how can I get number of threads in the code? am I able to get number of threads by `Threads.nthread()` in the code?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JULIA_NUM_THREADS` to set number of threads, note that this must be done *before* the julia process is started. You can read about [environment variables in the manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/environment-variables/#Environment-Variables-1).

Yes, the documentation for `Base.Threads.nthreads`:

```
help?> Base.Threads.nthreads
  Threads.nthreads()

  Get the number of threads available to the Julia process. This is the
  inclusive upper bound on threadid().
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. is there any command to make threads in the code, not in the terminal? like what `addprocs()` does?

Comment: No, they need to be added before Julia is opened.

Comment: Yes, as Chis said, `JULIA_NUM_THREADS` needs to be set before the julia process is started. Edited my answer to clarify that.